# Typing issue with custom hook that accept any function as parameter, whatever the return type is or arguments are

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I wrote a custom hook that accept an async function as parameter.

Everything is working as expected with functions that have no parameter :

```js
type UseAsyncOperationResult<TResult> = {
  status: "idle" | "pending" | "success" | "error";
  fire: () => Promise<void>;
  error?: Error;
  data?: TResult;
};

type UseAsyncOperationOptions<TResult> = {
  onSuccess?: (result: TResult) => void;
  onError?: (error: Error) => void;
  autofire?: boolean;
};

export const useAsyncOperation = <TResult>(
  operation: () => Promise<TResult>,
  options: UseAsyncOperationOptions<TResult> = {}
): UseAsyncOperationResult<TResult> => {
... actual code ...
}

// within a component:

const computeAsync = (x: number, y: number): Promise<number> => {
  const result = x * y;
  console.log(`Computing ${x}*${y}=${result}`);
  return Promise.resolve(result);
};

  const [x, setX] = useState(10);
  const [y, setY] = useState(10);

  const { data, fire } = useAsyncOperation(
    () => {
      return computeAsync(x, y);
    },
    { autofire: true }
  );
```

The idea is to return an object that has a `fire` property, which has exactly the same signature than the operation parameter, and a `data` property that is in this example `number` (data is ready) or `undefined` (data is not ready)

this works well when sticking on function that has no parameters.

Working sample here: [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-moon-dtw28q?file=/src/useAsyncOperation.ts).

I'd like to extend the hook to accept any function with any number or arguments.

I tried to type my function like this:

```js
type UseAsyncOperationResult<TResult, TArgs extends never[]> = {
    status: 'idle' | 'pending' | 'success' | 'error';
    fire: (...args: TArgs) => Promise<void>;
    error: Error | undefined;
    data: TResult | undefined;
};

type UseAsyncOperationOptions<TResult, TArgs extends never[]> = {
    onSuccess?: (result: TResult) => void;
    onError?: (error: Error) => void;
    autofire?: TArgs;
};

export const useAsyncOperation = <
    TResult,
    TArgs extends never[],
    TOperation extends (...args: TArgs) => Promise<TResult>
>(
    operation: TOperation,
    options: UseAsyncOperationOptions<TResult, TArgs> = {}
): UseAsyncOperationResult<TResult, TArgs> => {
... actual code ...
}
```

However, the typings are not properly handled.

For example, if I use:

```js
    const computeAsync = useCallback((x: number, y: number): Promise<number> => {
        const result = x * y;
        console.log(`Computing ${x}*${y}=${result}`);
        return Promise.resolve(result);
    }, []);

    const {
        status,
        data,
        error
    } = useAsyncOperation(computeAsync, { autofire: [2, 3] });
```

The `data` variable is understood as `unknown` by typescript, the expected type (should be `number`)

Another [sandbox is available](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-currying-of14k5?file=/src/App.tsx) with the extended hook, which is not compiling.

The relevant code in the sandbox is

```js
const computeAsync = (x: number, y: number): Promise<number> => {
  const result = x * y;
  console.log(`Computing ${x}*${y}=${result}`);
  return Promise.resolve(result);
};


// within a component :
  const [x, setX] = useState(10);

  const { data, fire } = useAsyncOperation(
    (y: number) => {
      return computeAsync(x, y);
    },
    { autofire: [10] }
  );
```

How can I fix my code ?

Comment: Would this work for you? I've only changed the `useAsyncOperation` signature  to use `Awaited<ReturnType<TOperation>>` instead of `TResult` https://tsplay.dev/mZQz4N

Comment: The `TArgs extends never[]` looks weird to me. Maybe you mean `unknown` instead of `never`?

Comment: tested with `unknown`. It has exactly the same behavior. I used never because I tried to mimic the `useCallback` definition

Comment: @A_A: does not compiles at all

Comment: What do you mean it does not compile at all? In the playground link the only error is because of the never[] use, with unknown[] this compiles

Comment: @A_A: I mean when applied to the actual code. Inside the hook body, there are compilation issue (cannot match `TResult` to `Awaited<ReturnType<TOperation>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it seems to work as expected :

```js
    type UseAsyncOperationResult<TResult, TArgs extends [...any[]]> = {
        status: "idle" | "pending" | "success" | "error";
        fire: (...args: TArgs) => Promise<void>;
        error: Error | undefined;
        data: TResult | undefined;
    };
    
    type UseAsyncOperationOptions<TResult, TArgs extends [...any[]]> = {
        onSuccess?: (result: TResult) => void;
        onError?: (error: Error) => void;
        autofire?: TArgs;
    };
    
    export const useAsyncOperation = <
        TResult,
        TArgs extends [...any[]]
    >(
            operation: (...args: TArgs) => Promise<TResult>,
            options: UseAsyncOperationOptions<TResult, TArgs> = {},
        ): UseAsyncOperationResult<TResult, TArgs> => {
        throw new Error("NotImplemented");
    };
```

The main difference is to use `[...any[]]` instead of `never[]`.

Comment: Thanks! it seems to work. I use `[...unknown[]]` because of qualifty restrictions . However, I don't get why its working. What are the brackets around the array ?

Comment: For future readers, here is sandbox that includes Romain's suggestion : https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-surf-bwz6ck?file=/src/useAsyncOperation.ts

Comment: when using `[...unknown[]]` your not saying an array of unknown items but a tuple of unknown items, tuples and arrays are difernet in many ways, notably : tuple is fixed length and fixed order of items. when you create a function type `(...args: [string,number]) => any` it equals `(a:string, b: number) => any` wich is very different of `(...args: (string|number)[]) => any`. Hopes it's clearer as it's not very easy to explain :/

Comment: I think I get the point. Very valuable because it solved my issue and helped me to learn something:)